# Data Dump in to Mongo collection from spring boot app

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection named `person` and i store the below data in to it (i get the below data by calling another API)

```
{
"personId" : "457665xxxxx988765",
"personName" : "Arun",
"personaAge" : 25,
"personAddress" : "India",
"personPhoneNumber" : "8988999";
"personCompany" : "Google",
"personBike" : "Honda"
}
```

It gets stored in my collection as

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5ef998776801"),
"personId" : "457665xxxxx988765",
"personName" : "Arun",
"personaAge" : 25,
"personAddress" : "India",
"personPhoneNumber" : "8988999";
"personCompany" : "Google",
"personBike" : "Honda"
}
```

I have 8000 records like this.. Daily, as part of a batch-job i get around 8000 records and i will have to update my collection. If the `personId` is already there then i will have to update that `person-record` or else i will have to create a new data in to the collection.

I can do this by looping my data and `check-if-person-id-already-exists`, then update the data or else `create-new-data`.

But this will attract 8K DB calls .. is there any way to do this at one shot ?  Am using spring-boot in my server to connect to Mongo

Comment: What is the version of your MongoDB? Is `personId` unique?

Comment: yes. it is unique

Comment: Nice. MongoDB version?

Comment: `MongoDB 4.0.9 Enterprise`

Comment: My solution requieres MongoDB 4.2 to use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/). Is it possible upgrade your MongoDB version to 4.2? The main idea: We insert into temp collection your daily input data (or we can call mongoimport as well). We perform aggregate with the last stage `$merge` which will insert into your main collection new records (whenNotMatched:insert) and/or update already existed personId records (whenMatched:replace).